# MongoDB return where array contains at least one item from query array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection with records that have a `tags` field, similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "foo",
    "tags": [ "fizz", "buzz", "quz" ]
  }
]
```

I would like to be able to search these against an array, so I could search for records matching at least one of the passed in array values, so query with `[ "fizz" ]` would match, or `[ "fizz", "quz" ]` would match but `[ "bar" ]` would not.

I've tried `$elemMatch` but that seems to only return the record when *all* elements from the query array match the `tags` array in the record.

Answer (score 0):

The [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/in/index.html#in) query operator should accomplish what you need:

For a quick demo, I created a collection with several variations of an array:

```
[
  { arr: [ "a", "b", "c" ] },
  { arr: [ "b", "c", "d" ] },
  { arr: [ "c", "d", "e" ] },
  { arr: [ "d", "e", "f" ] }
]
```

Query for documents that contain "a" or "b" returns the first 2:

```
db.collection.find({ arr: { $in: [ "a", "b", ] } })
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qE6kY5t_qW8)